# Is it possible to delay, or cancel a view from disappearing?

Tags: ios

I'm utilizing `viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool)` to push data to my server, as an `auto-save` type feature.  However, sometimes there is an event where the data that a user has entered is incomplete, or invalid so I don't want to push it to the server. In this event I present an `UIAlertController` that displays a notification.

Currently the notification just allows the user to dismiss it, but it would be exponentially more beneficial to allow the user to have the option to stay on the page and correct it, if they wanted to.

Basically, I want to prevent the view from changing, until after the user makes a choice on the presented `UIAlertController`. If this is not possible, then I would at the least send the users back to the previous view, granted they select that option.

Currently my application uses a custom Segue provided by the [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) library, called `reveal view controller, push controller` which allows me to use the navigation drawer on the view that I've navigated to. Without doing this, the application will crash.

Unfortunately using `self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)` in the callback of an `UIAlertAction` doesn't yield any results.

**EDIT:**
To anyone reading this in the future, I have a work-around solution, which may, or may not be the correct way to handle this. Instead of linking a button to a segue for navigation, create a manual segue merging each view. (You can do this by right click + dragging from one view to the other), once you've done this take your button and create an `@IBAction` for it, this `@IBAction` should display the `UIAlertController` and inside of the `UIAlertAction` you should call your segue manually using `performSegueWithIdentifier` whenever you want to move to the next view. If you want to stay on the view, you simply do not call it.

Once again this may, or may not be the correct way to handle this, but unless someone tells me another more proper way, this is how I will be handling it.

Comment: Currently, I have found a work-around for this, calling the segue manually and executing code to show the alert while completely bypassing the need for `viewWillDisappear`. however would like a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the method in your edit is correct. What we most commonly do is have a button or any other action that will start sending, evaluating the data and at the same time add some activity indicator to the view so the user knows he needs to wait for a task to finish.

After that is done it depends on the case. Either we navigate to the new screen on success or give the user some alert view indicating the operation is done or in some cases even display some text or an image indicating the operation is done which is shown for a second or so and then navigate to the other screen. If error occurres we display some indication of that and stay on the screen naturally.

Where your problems seemed to have started is actually abusing the storyboard feature. You should know this type of development might get you into a lot of trouble. I suggest you to avoid segues at all cost. Even and as specially if you are then calling them in the code. Simply call `navigationController.pop` or `push`, `present`, `dismiss`, `setViewControllers`... But even if you do keep using them keep in mind that this is just some shortcut for you and you should still understand how to do all of these in the code.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep this in mind. I've only started iOS development about two weeks ago and have finished my application already. (Fairly large scale social networking application using Parse as a backend). It was both a learning project and a great experience. 

The issue (currently) is that the library I'm using is dependent on segues. I'll be writing my own navigation drawer here soon that's native to swift. 

I was using all of the navigationController functions, before I started using the navigation drawer library. Thanks again for your words.